# Why should I care if a network switch has "buffer memory"?

Tags: networking, switch

I'm looking at purchasing a network switch, and the only spec I'm not sure of is one specifying "buffer memory" per port. What is that used for?

Answer (score 3):

It is used to buffer packets in a store-and-forward switch.  More buffers are not neccesarily better, and can even make things *worse*.  See the [Buffer Bloat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bufferbloat) phenomenon.  Cut-through switches provide much lower latency and do not use buffers.

Comment: Note though that for some workloads, larger port buffers can offer significant performance improvements. iSCSI SAN traffic, for example.

Comment: So I should just ignore that particular spec?

Comment: @Chris Thorpe, it shouldn't help at all, and due to the buffer bloat problem, could make things worse.  More buffered packets leads to more latency.

Comment: @Billy ONeal, I would look for cut-through switches that don't use buffers.

Comment: @psusi: Hmmm... I don't see anything like that available anywhere. Then again, I'm talking about a small (~8 port) switch. Everything available seems to be store-and-forward.

Comment: @Billy ONeal, then for the most part pay no attention to it, except if you see any with ridiculously large buffers ( > 128k ), and avoid those.